# What does the word "as-yet-unknown" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does the word `as-yet-unknown` mean in the following sentence?

```
Andrews, 31, plans to sue the as-yet-unknown person who shot the
footage -- and anyone publishing the material.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*As-yet-unknown* means "currently unknown." In your sentence, Andrews does not yet know who the person who shot the footage is. However, he plans on suing him or her, as soon as he figures out who s/he is.

Comment: "whot"?  That's really a hoot!  ;-)

Answer (score 8):

`as-yet-unknown` means that it is an unknown quantity (in the case above, that the person hasn't been identified).  It also indicates that while that is the current state of things, that they are or will be working to identify the person.

Comment: I like claudiu's stab at an answer, but I particularly like your assertion that they 'will be working to identify the person', which I think reflects the case nicely.